# Squaring every single item in a 2D list

Tags: python, sublist, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

So I have a large list of points.
I have split those points up into the x coordinates and the y coordinates and then further split them into groups of 1000.

```
x = [points_Cartesian[x: x + 1000, 0] for x in range(0, len(points_Cartesian), 1000)]
```

(The y coordinates looks the same but with y instead of x.)

I am trying to turn the cartesian points into polar and to do so I must square every item in x and every item in y.

```
for sublist1 in x:
   temp1 = []
   for inte1 in sublist1:
       temp1.append(inte1**2)
   xSqua.append(temp1)
```

After that I add both of the Squared values together and square root them to get rad.

```
rad = np.sqrt(xSqua + ySqua)
```

The problem is, I started with 10,000 points and somewhere in this code it gets trimmed down to 1,000.
Does anyone know what the error is and how I fix it?

Comment: What are the types of `xSqua` and `ySqua`? Can you try post a MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  that shows the issue?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Convert a `10000x2` array of x- and y-coordinates to polar coordinates? Where does the "split into groups of 1000" come in?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: You posted code snippets from two phases of your program.  Instead, post a small, *running* example of the phase that fails for you.  Look into using list comprehensions or NumPy to make this flow better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using `numpy`. You can reshape matrices using [`numpy.reshape()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and square the entire array elementwise using the `**` operator on the entire array and your code will be much faster than iterating.

For example, let's say we have a 10000x3 `points_cartesian`

```
points_Cartesian = np.random.random((10000,2))
# reshape to 1000 columns, as many rows as required
xpts = points_Cartesian[:, 0].reshape((-1, 1000)) 
ypts = points_Cartesian[:, 1].reshape((-1, 1000))

# elementwise square using **
rad = np.sqrt(xpts**2 + ypts**2)
ang = np.arctan2(ypts, xpts)
```

Now `rad` and `ang` are `10x1000` arrays.